# ipywidget combination from a user defined function

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to create multiple widgets for multiple 'rows' with a function in Jupyter Notebook and enable/disable some of those rows based on a checkbox. The widgets are created properly. But when i try to select/unselect the rows, it only works for the first click.

```
%matplotlib widget

import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Output, Layout, GridBox, VBox, HBox, Box

OUT = Output()

def create_widgets(name):
    
    def test(event):

        OUT.clear_output()
        with OUT:
            print(event.old, event.new)
    
        if event.new:
            dd.disabled = False
            bt.disabled = False
        else:
            dd.disabled = True
            bt.disabled = False
    
    
    cb = widgets.Checkbox(
        value=True, 
        #description='', 
        disabled=False, 
        indent=False)
    
    cb.observe(test)

    
    dd = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=['1', '2', '3'],
        value='2',
        description=name,
        disabled=False,
        layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px'),
        style = {'description_width': 'initial'})   

    bt = widgets.BoundedIntText(
        value=7,
        min=5,
        max=25,
        step=0.5,
        description='val',
        disabled=False,
        layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px'),
        style = {'description_width': 'initial'})
    
    box_layout = Layout(width='250px', height='auto')
    box = HBox([cb, dd, bt], layout=box_layout)
    
    return box
    

A = create_widgets('A')
B = create_widgets('B')
C = create_widgets('C')
# add some more 
INPUT =  VBox([A, B, C])
display(INPUT, OUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to look at what your debugging `print()` statements reveal. `event.new` is never anything. (I don't know if that is a bug or someone decided `new` was moot for a checkbox?) So your conditional `if event.new:` can never be `True`.

Anyways, the value under `event.owner.value` or `event['owner'].value` is consistent with the checkbox setting and doesn't seem counterintuitively named, like `event.old`. And so you can use that in your conditional, like so:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Output, Layout, GridBox, VBox, HBox, Box

OUT = Output()

def create_widgets(name):
    
    def test(event):

        OUT.clear_output()
        with OUT:
            print(event)
            print(event.old, event.new)
            print(event.owner.value)
    
        if event.owner.value:
            dd.disabled = False
            bt.disabled = False
        else:
            dd.disabled = True
            bt.disabled = False
    
    
    cb = widgets.Checkbox(
        value=True, 
        #description='', 
        disabled=False, 
        indent=False)
    
    cb.observe(test)

    
    dd = widgets.Dropdown(
        options=['1', '2', '3'],
        value='2',
        description=name,
        disabled=False,
        layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px'),
        style = {'description_width': 'initial'})   

    bt = widgets.BoundedIntText(
        value=7,
        min=5,
        max=25,
        step=0.5,
        description='val',
        disabled=False,
        layout = widgets.Layout(width='100px'),
        style = {'description_width': 'initial'})
    
    box_layout = Layout(width='250px', height='auto')
    box = HBox([cb, dd, bt], layout=box_layout)
    
    return box
    

A = create_widgets('A')
B = create_widgets('B')
C = create_widgets('C')
# add some more 
INPUT =  VBox([A, B, C])
display(INPUT, OUT)
```

---

ASIDE:

These days, you don't need the `%matplolib ...` line in classic notebook. Or for using this code in JupyerLab where `ipympl` is installed.
You can see that in action by trying [classic](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?filepath=notebooks%2Fvoila_and_matplotlib.ipynb) or [JupyterLab](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb) **without touching your own system or needing to install anything** by using a temporary remote machine served by the MyBinder service. The code block just above will work in a cell in both places. **Note there is no `%matplotlib ...` as the first line or elsewhere** in that code block.